# PFQueryTable Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get videos that i saved to parse to show up in my tableview cell when i load the data but for some reason when i run the program the table view is blank. I have tried using UITableViewController instead of parse's but i couldn't get it to work that way either.  Is there any way i can get the video to show up in the tableview cell?

Code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    var song: NSURL!

    var player:MPMoviePlayerController!


    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.parseClassName = "Videos"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.objectsPerPage = 10
        self.paginationEnabled = true

    }

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
        var query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName)

        if (objects.count == 0)
        {
            query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly
        }

        return query


        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject! {
        var obj : PFObject? = nil
        if(indexPath.row < self.objects.count){
            obj = self.objects[indexPath.row] as PFObject
        }

        return obj
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PFTableViewCell

        let video:PFFile = object["musicVideo"] as PFFile
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: video.url)!



        println(video)


        player = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
        player.view.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
        cell.contentView.addSubview(player.view)
        player.view.hidden = false
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()




        return cell
    }



}
```

Comment: Did your cellForRowAtIndexPath function get called?

Comment: Also I don't see that your modify/add information(video url for example) to your PFTableViewCell cell object.

Comment: cell.contentView.addSubview(player.view) i add the player view to the cell contentview but that doesnt work.  I am sure that cellForRow gets callled

Comment: Sorry, I have not noticed that line of code. Seems your code is correct.
I would suggest to make sure:
1. you have valid objects in parse.com DB.
2. You are getting correct query results.
3. Check your 'player',  is it correct size.

Comment: 1. yes tested everything on parse works ok 2. cant print the query for some reason when i run println(query) nothing prints in console.  3. i set the player to be the size of the cell.contentView.   Thanks for helping me also.

Comment: I can also suggest to have a look on this example: https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic
It is in Objective C, but I think will be helpful to find your issue.
Have a look in PAPPhotoTimelineViewController.h/m file:
for cellForRowAtIndexPath function :)

Answer (score 0):

NB the correct code for setting the objects in a PFQueryTableViewController in Swift 1.2 appears to have changed slightly (force unwrapping to PFObject! will cause a crash when the last cell in the table is loaded, if it is not the "load more" cell, as will counting objects! instead of objects?).

```
    override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject? {
    var obj : PFObject? = nil
    if(indexPath.row < self.objects!.count){
        obj = self.objects?[indexPath.row] as? PFObject
    }

    return obj
}
```